# What is meant by wordform?

Tags: terminology

Wordforms are the inflicted forms of lemmas, which are of infinitive in nature.

Is the above definition true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct that way.

First of all, a lemma form is not necessarily infinitive: For Latin verbs, the 1st person singular present tense is chosen by convention as the lemma form, for nouns it is usually the nominative singular.

Second, there are a lot of words that don't inflect at all, think of prepositions (or postpositions), conjunctions, or adverbs. In their case, there is only one possible word form for a lemma.

A word form is any form of a word we see in an utterance, inflected or infinitive, identical to the lemma form or not. There are some fused word forms (e.g., German *am* = *an + dem*, Italian *nella* = *in + la*) made from two or even more lemmas. An we can have the opposite case: One lemma split into two words, as in the infamous German splitable verbs, e.g. *ansehen* ("to look at", lemma) *sie sieht mich an* "she looks at me" where *sieht* and *an* are the two parts of *ansehen* in this sample sentence.